# Load results dynamically (Google maps API) on change bounds (pan or zoom)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm using AngularJS NgMap together with MarkerClusterer to display a bunch of markers on a map. Currently I'm loading all the results into a map but I want to change this behavior to load the results partially - within the bounds of the current map view and when the user scrolls across the map to load other markers accordingly. I'm really bad with JS so I really need help with it.

This is my controller code for loading all the results into the map:

```
application.controller('mapController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', 'StreetView', 'NgMap', function ( $scope, $http, $log, $timeout, StreetView, NgMap ) {

var vm = this;

vm.stores = [];

console.log ('App is loaded');

NgMap.getMap().then(function(evtMap) {

    // Map marker styles

    var clusterer_styles = [[{
        url: url_static + 'img/mc-small.png',
        height: 34,
        width: 34,
        anchor: [0, 0],
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        textSize: 10
    }, {
        url: url_static + 'img/mc-medium-green.png',
        fontFamily: '"Poppins Semi", Arial',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        anchor: [0, 0],
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        textSize: 12
    }, {
        url: url_static + 'img/mc-large.png',
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        anchor: [0, 0],
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        textSize: 13
    }]];

    map = evtMap;
    vm.map = map;
    $http.get( url_root + 'data/rentals-results.php').then(function(resp) {
        var stores = resp.data;
        // Close the info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            angular.element('#map-detail-info').hide();
        });

        for (var i=0; i<stores.length; i++) {
            var store = stores[i];

            var loc = store.latlon.split(',');

            store.position = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0],loc[1]);
            store.title = store.property_name;
            store.icon = url_static + 'img/real-map-icon.png';
            if ( store.price_from < 100 ) {
                if ( store.price_to > 1 ) {
                    store.labelContent = '$' + store.price_to;
                } else {
                    store.labelContent = 'Ask';
                }
            } else {
                store.labelContent = '$' + store.price_from;
            }

            store.labelAnchor = new google.maps.Point(25, 31);
            store.labelClass = "map-label-dash"; // the CSS class for the label
            store.labelInBackground =  false;
            // Push the marker
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel(store);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

                return function() {

                    marker.setIcon( url_static + 'img/real-map-icon-active.png' );

                    display_map_item( stores[i] );
                }
            })(marker, i));

            vm.stores.push(marker);
        }
        console.log('finished loading scripts/starbucks.json', 'vm.stores', vm.stores.length);
        // Hide the loader
        angular.element('.loading-anim').fadeOut();
        // Marker Clusterer init

        vm.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, vm.stores, {
             styles: clusterer_styles[0],
            'imagePath': url_static + 'img/m'
        });
    }, function(err) { console.log('err', err)});
});


// Display map item on click marker
function display_map_item( item ) {
    angular.element('#map-detail-info').show();
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.item_result = item;
    });
}
```

}]);

The HTML part is:

```
 <ng-map center="[39.740205, -105.006911]"
                   zoom="12"
                   pan-control="true"
                   pan-control-options="{position:'TOP_RIGHT'}"
                   map-type-control="true"
                   map-type-control-options="{style:'HORIZONTAL_BAR', position:'TOP_CENTER'}"
                   zoom-control="true"
                   zoom-control-options="{style:'LARGE', position:'LEFT_CENTER'}"
                   scale-control="true"
                   street-view-control="true"
                   street-view-control-options="{position:'RIGHT_BOTTOM'}"
                   default-style="false">
           </ng-map>
```

Also the changed bounds (lat and lon) needs to be appended to the URL from where I fetch the results, somehow like:

```
$http.get( url_root + 'data/rentals-results.php?lat=' + new_lat + '&lng=' + new_lon)
```

Thanks